# Find the interval for the power series: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+2)!}{n!}\left(x+2\right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+2)!}{n!}\left(x+2\right)^n$$

To solve I used the ratio test and just wanted to see if my method was correct:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{\left(n+1+2\right)!}{\left(n+1\right)!}\left(x+2\right)^{n+1}\bullet\frac{n!}{\left(n+2\right)!\left(x+2\right)^n}\right|$$

Attempting to simplify this gave me:

$$\left(x+2\right)\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{(n+3)!}{(n+1)!}\bullet\frac{n!}{(n+2)!}\right|$$

Which ultimately leaves me with:

$$\left(x+2\right)$$

Solving this for the interval gives me $-3 \lt x \lt -1$

Is my method here correct?

Comment: That's correct but what about when $x = -3$ or $x = 1$?  The ratio test is inconclusive in those two cases so you need to handle them individually.  It seems pretty obvious that those two cases will diverge.

Comment: @Jared I honestly forgot how to test the end points!  I'm looking it up now

Comment: In both cases you get $1^n = 1$ and $(-1)^n = \{-1, 1\}$, respectively.  Surely you can show that the sequence doesn't converge to $0$ from those two cases and thus the series diverges.  Hint: which is bigger, $(n + 2)!$ or $n!$?